# How JAXBContext.newInstance can cause memory leak

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, jaxb

I have read a lot of post (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584821/jaxbcontext-newinstance-memory-leak), [this](http://www.scorgar.be/blog/lessons-learned-memory-leak-in-webservices-with-jaxb/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851516/tomcat-and-jaxb-memory-leaks/18852542)) and they suggests that `JAXBContext.newInstance` caused memory leak, now my understanding is that once method execution is over, all local objects created inside the method will be eligible for GC, so I wonder that how `JAXBContext.newInstance` caused memory.

Comment: https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/issues/831

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons is that JAXB runtime uses `ThreadLocal` [here and there](https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=threadlocal&type=), sometimes static. This may be a source of memory leaks:

> [ThreadLocal & Memory Leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968803/threadlocal-memory-leak)